# Why does a savepoint error appear in this situation?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, transactions

Why does an error "ORA-01086: savepoint 'X' never established in this session or is invalid" appear on execution of this block?

```
begin

  savepoint X;

  execute immediate 'alter package ANY_EXISTING_PACKAGE compile';

  rollback to X;

end;
```

Comment: You cannot rollback to a savepoint with DDL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDL does an implicit commit prior to running and either a rollback or commit afterwards. Therefore, your savepoint X in the above example is no longer applicable following the attempt to compile your package.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/sqllangu.htm#sthref808